# Variables C macro function

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

What's happening in this macro? I understand that #test expand this parameter to the literal text. But what does `pre;` and `test;` do?

```
#define MACRO_FN(test, pre, repeat, size)    \
  do {                                     \
    printf("%s: ", #test);                 \
    for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {     \
      pre;                                 \
      test;                                \
    }                                      \
  } while (0)
```

This is used like so

```
MACRO_FN(a_func(an_array, size),, var1, size);
```

What do the double commas mean here?

Comment: Run the code through the preprocessor and look what the macro expands to.

Comment: To omit `pre;`- maybe? Did you check the pre-processed code?

Comment: I didn't think to check the output of the pre-processor, but I'll do that now

Comment: When invoking a preprocessor macro , "blank" is a valid argument; the call `MACRO_FN(a,,b,c)` means that `pre` will expand to blank

Comment: Could you show a [MCVE]?

Comment: Please note that macros like these should be avoided like the plague.

Comment: @JackEvans: You are missing the closing bracket for the `for` loop, so I don't understand how this works. This is a rather terrible idea for a macro, btw, but whoever wrote it probably didn't realize you can pass two calls as a single parameter (using `MACRO_FN({test1();test2();}, var, 100);` or `MACRO_FN((test1(),test2()), var, 100);`).

Comment: Yes, this isn't my code, I am just trying to understand it. I have removed some parts of the macro

Comment: What is `repeat`. It's nowhere in the question. We need a **[mcve]**.

Comment: @JackEvans: I would presume the point of this is to repeat a function call several times, probably to measure execution time (e.g. a variant of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39729876/69809)). So whoever wrote it presumably wanted to avoid the overhead of calling the function through a function pointer, which could make sense if the function is `static inline`. It it's not production code, the idea could generally pass for benchmarking, but this `pre` argument is complete nonsense IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a minimal example:

```
#define repeat 5    // I added this, because 'repeat' is not mentionned in your question

#define MACRO_FN(test, pre, var1, size)    \
  do {                                     \
    printf("%s: ", #test);                 \
    for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {     \
      pre;                                 \
      test;                                \
    }                                      \
  } while (0)

void foo()
{
}

void func(int a, int b)
{
}

int main()
{
  MACRO_FN(func(2, 3), foo(), var1, size);
}
```

Once preprocessed, the code is equivalent to this:

```
int main()
{
  printf("%s: ", "func(2,3)");
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    foo();
    func(2, 3);
  }
}
```

So that macro is a wrapper that prints the function name plus it's parameters as it is invoked with the macro and executes that function specified in the first parameter `repeat` times (whatever `repeat` is). If the second parameter is omitted, the function that has that name is simple not invoked before the function mentioned before as in the following example:

```
int main()
{
  MACRO_FN(func(2, 3),, var1, size);
}
```

Once preprocessed, the code is equivalent to this:

```
int main()
{
  printf("%s: ", "func(2,3)");
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    ;
    func(2, 3);
  }
}
```

**Note**:

I removed the `do while(0)` from the equivalent programs for brevity, read [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for) for more information:

Answer (score 3):

`pre` and `test` seem to be two functions.
Based on how it is written, we can guess that `pre` is a function called before the `test`.

The double comma has no special meaning. It is just here because the second parameter (`pre`) was omitted.

Edit: As a side note that kind of macro "should be avoided like plague", as @Lundin put it.